# SphinxQL error really basic

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

Here's my query:

```
SELECT `person_id` FROM `123numbers` WHERE MATCH('john smith')
```

Here's the error I get:

```
[1064] sphinxql: syntax error, unexpected $undefined, expecting IDENT near '`123numbers` WHERE MATCH('john smith')' [ SELECT `person_id` FROM `123numbers` WHERE MATCH('john smith')]
```

What is wrong? I've simplified my query to the extreme and it still doesn't work.

Thanks for help! ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently an index name cannot start with a number using SphinxQL, but using the API, everything is fine.

```
*BUG*
```